# Order/Sort cxGrid in alphabetical order of a field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

How does one order/sort a cxGrid in alphabetical order of a field?

Thanks,

Comment: Managed to work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'SortOrder' property on grid field column - soAscending